# Using MySQL queries solve the below table

Tags: mysql

```
Cname   Iyear   Ivalue
A   1999    100
B   2000    125
A   2001    150
A   2000    100
A   2001    150
B   2003    500
```

And so on…

Connect  to the MYSQL  and Get the output in A TABLE as under.

```
    1999    2000    2001    2003
A    100     100     300      
B            125             500
```

Comment: I'm not able to figure out what your specific programming question is.

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score -1):

May be this will help You :

```
 select Cname,group_concat(Iyear) as Iyear,group_concat(Ivalue) as Ivalue 
 from table 
 group by Cname
 order by Iyear asc
```